# Pipe 2 files through 2 programs in the Windows command prompt

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

I'm learning how to use the command prompt on my Windows OS and can't seem to find an answer to what I'm sure is a simple problem: I'm trying to pipe two data files through two python programs in the command line, but it seems that the data isn't making it through. Here is my input (My data files and programs are saved in the same directory, which I'm already working from):

```
type file1.txt file2.txt | C:\pathToPython\python program1.py | C:\path\python program2.py > output.txt
```

Is there some syntax that I'm missing? An explanation would be quite helpful, thanks!

**EDIT: Adding Error Information.**

The program throws an error in the second program:

```
IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes
```

This seemed to me to indicate that the data was not piping through correctly; the programs were functioning correctly when I ran them separately, until I tried to pipe both simultaneously and added in `file2`

Comment: It depends on what you're doing in program1.py and program2.py to read from `sys.stdin` and write to `sys.stdout`.

Comment: @eryksun It's a mapreduce algorithm. The mapper executes a for loop extracting several variables from `sys.stdin`. Then the reducer uses the output from the mapper to create a dictionary and calculate percentiles based on the dictionary, which are the output in `output.txt`. I assumed it must be a problem with my command prompts since the python programs themselves seemed solid to me. Does my command above seem correct, then?

Comment: I tried a similar command line with 2 simple scripts that loop over `stdin` and print to `stdout`, and it worked fine with both Python 3.5.2 and 2.7.12 in Windows 10. So the devil will be in the details of your scripts.